# Can we implement parallel code for Fibonacci series using apache spark

Tags: apache-spark, parallel-processing, cluster-computing

By apache spark, I understand that it is used for leveraging the computational power of more than one computer called nodes. Can we use this high computational power for quickly finding some nth fibonacci number..? If so, how is that possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely.

A closed form solution of the Fibonacci sequence is given on [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) by:

[image: formula]

Assign one or more binomial coefficients to each node/processor/computer, and sum up the result.

QED

Comment: Is there any sample spark code available to achieve this?

Comment: @user39602 Stack Overflow is a site for coding help, not a code writing service.  Questions posted must contain the non-working code or non-compilable code, showing an attempt to solve the coding problem by the OP.  Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, demos, sample code and more are "off-topic" for Stack Overflow.  The above question contained no code, and should be off-topic.  It contained a "Can we ..." question, and got this "Absolutely" tongue in cheek answer (albeit with mildly useful additional detail).  To your question, "is sample code available?"  Probably.